# StreamWriter text file gets created but contains no lines

Tags: vb.net, winforms, filestream, streamwriter

I'm trying to write some text lines to a little log file in a Windows Form application and I cannot see why no lines are written. The file gets created OK and all of the following executes without error but when I open the new file with Notepad, there are no lines. Key snippets follow:

```
    Dim sFileName = App_Path() & "\logs\" & sJobName & ".log"
    Try
        Using fs As FileStream = New FileStream(sFileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)
            Using w As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fs)
                Dim s As String = "Beginning execution (JobName=" & sJobName & ")"
                Log(s, w)
                s = "Connection in effect: " & BuildConnectString()
                Log(s, w)
                Dim loader As New Importer
                loader.LoadData(Me.txtFN.Text, w)
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

Public Sub Log(logMessage As String, w As StreamWriter)
    w.WriteLine("{0} {1}: {2}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), _
        DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), logMessage)
End Sub
```

and then I'm trying to write to this log from a different class which has been passed the StreamWriter as a parameter:

```
Public Function LoadData(ByRef filename As String, _
                         ByRef w As StreamWriter) As String
    Dim s As String = "Test logging from loader class"
    Mainform.Log(s, w)
```

In this little test, I am expecting to see 3 lines but I'm getting nothing. I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: This code works for me. May be there is something else in the code (that you have not mentioned here) that is creating the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me, but if the code doesn't work for you, you can use code like this ...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sFileName = App_Path() & "\logs\" & sJobName & ".log"
    Try
        Dim s As String = "Beginning execution (JobName=" & sJobName & ")"
        Log(s, sFileName)
        s = "Connection in effect: " & BuildConnectString()
        Log(s, sFileName)
        Dim loader As New Importer
        loader.LoadData(Me.txtFN.Text, sFileName)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub Log(logMessage As String, StrPath As String)
    IO.File.AppendAllText(StrPath, String.Format("{0} {1}: {2}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), logMessage) + vbCrLf)
End Sub

Public Function LoadData(ByRef filename As String, _
                     StrPath As String) As String
    Dim s As String = "Test logging from loader class"
    Log(s, StrPath)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm curious what you meant by "works for me..". Are you saying my code in the original post with USING statements worked properly for you? I debugged all that code line by line and it executed without error but no lines were present in the .log file.

Comment: I tried your code and it "worked" for me but I have 2 problems with it. The doc for AppendAllText states that it "Opens a file, appends the specified string to the file, and then closes the file. If the file does not exist, this method creates a file, writes the specified string to the file, then closes the file.". I'd like to be able to just write one line after another as needed without the overhead of closing and re-opening the file. Secondly, I need each string passed to the Log sub written as a separate line (i.e. appended to the file itself only - not appended to the prior line content.

Comment: Yes,i meant that your code is working and i saw the three line in the text, but i don't understand the problem with you, can you write the whole LoadData function ?

Comment: Very helpful comment you just made above. My original code is now working. I believe I now understand the Using and End Using functionality a bit better. I was single-stepping through the code with the debugger. After successful execution of the Log method inside the LoadData function, I'd click "End Debugging" which of course bypassed the execution of the End Using. So even though LoadData has lots more work to do, I added a quick return after the invoke of the Log method which returned to the End Using and all is fine now. I want to give you credit for helping me.

Comment: Please post a brief answer which confirms that the End Using is needed to "flush the pending buffer(s)" or whatever best way to say this. I DO STILL believe the usage of Streamwriter is better than the repeated overhead of IO.File.AppendAllText which continually re-opens and closes the log file. When you can, please post a brief answer so I can give you points.

Comment: I have never used the StreamWriter or FileStream(just small cases) in my projects, because i want to close the file to write on it from another thread or from another program, so i'm using the IO.File.Usage always and i don't think there is a problem about that, if you think that, you can use EmptyWorkingSet function in the big projects to free the memory, to relax with coding without wasting time on these small errors, another point that i don't want to lost all my log if the program closed when the program in the middle of using StreamWriter, some codes need long time to get the information.

Comment: Thanks again. You make some very good points. Happy to mark your answer as the one.